# Is there some geometric understanding of a Jordan normal matrix?

Tags: intuition, jordan-normal-form

We know that an eigenvalue decomposition of a matrix is to find those eigenvectors that are just scale for some coefficients. But what about Jordan matrix decomposition? I just learn how it is calculated, but I am not sure whether it has geometric intuition.

Comment: A matrix is diagonalizable (i.e., you can find a basis of eigenvectors and interpret the matrix in that basis as just performing stretching along those eigenvectors) if you can express the domain as a vector space spanned by its eigenvectors. The Jordan normal form describes what happens when that is not possible. You can always find a basis of generalized eigenvectos. That means that if you cannot span the domain with eigenvectors of the matrix, you can do it by looking at generalized eigenvectors that are the preferred stretch directions of powers of the matrix.

Comment: @AnCar You could write that verbatim as an answer. That way, this question wouldn't appear as unanswered.

Comment: Maybe, but I prefer to write answers that have a bit more math meat to them. So if the poster wants to clarify if he needs more details or something more concrete, I will phrase that as an answer.